# Delphi firemonkey TButton with dropdown menu on left click?

Tags: delphi, button, firemonkey, dropdown

I need to have dropdown menus on TButton, when the button is clicked with the left mouse button.

I use the following code in the button's onClick event:

```
procedure TForm1.button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    pt:TPointF;
begin
    pt.X:=0;
    pt.Y:=button1.Height;
    pt:=button1.LocalToAbsolute(pt);
    pt:=ClientToScreen(pt);
    popupmenu1.Popup(pt.X,pt.y);
end;
```

This works fine with Windows as target platform, it also works on OSX, but when I click the button fast a couple of times, it crash on OSX (not so on Windows, there's no issue).

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? What kind of crash is it exactly? Please be more specific. It sounds like a possible FireMonkey bug, did you [report it to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com) yet?

Comment: I did not report it yet, because I am not sure I do something wrong, even I dont see anything wrong in my code. On Mac, it popup an Access violation accessing address 00000051. I am using Delphi 10.1 Update 2.

Comment: an AV at a low address near 0 implies a nil pointer is being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Must have been a bug in 10.1 Update 2.
I just installed Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, and it works.

Comment: probably something with calling popup while the popup was open(ing) I guess